# Cannot access folder xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

I have `htdocs/myproject/web` folder but I cannot access that `web` folder, i can access all others folders inside `htdocs/myproject/`. It doesn't show when I open localhost in web browser and it shows folder structre. Other folders are showing, where could be problem ? .. This project is downloaded from SVN.

Comment: Is your folder write-protected or hidden? If you've got a linux machine, run  ```ls -ll```.

Comment: That was correct, There was .htaccess file inside folder, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if there is a `.htaccess` file in the directory where indexing is disabled (for example `Options -Indexes`).